# How to join result from two select query

Tags: sql

i have two table table1 and table2 ItemId foreing key to Table 2

Table 1

```
|itemsId | Item | Quantity|
----------------------------
1 | item | 20
```

Table 2

```
|ItemId | Status | Quantity 
---------------------------
1 |Item Out| 5
```

I subtract quantity in table1 - table2 and assign the value in New Column Called Remain now the problem is i want join the result column with table 1 and table2

```
ItemId | Item | Quantity | Remaining |
---------------------------------------
1 | item | 20 | 15
```

I have try This

```
SELECT *
FROM (select i.ItemsId,i.Date,s.[Item Name],i.Quantity,i.[Recieved By],i.[From],i.[Reference No]
      from Store s inner join
           ItemsMovement i
           on s.ItemsId = i.ItemsId
      group by i.ItemsId
     ) T1 INNER JOIN 
     (select SUM(a.Quantity - b.Quantity) AS Remaining
      FROM Store a inner join
           ItemsMovement b
           on a.ItemsId = b.ItemsId 
      where b.Status ='Items In'
      group by a.ItemsId
     ) T2
```

Comment: Your SQL is ill-formed.  The `JOIN` has no `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want more easily with conditional aggregation:

```
select i.ItemsId, i.Date, s.[Item Name], i.Quantity, i.[Recieved By],
       i.[From],i.[Reference No],
       sum(case when i.Status = 'Items In' then s.Quantity - i.Quantity end) as remaining
from Store s inner join
     ItemsMovement i
     on s.ItemsId = i.ItemsId
group by i.ItemsId;
```

Comment: thanks, but i try this code throw this error " Column 'ItemsMovement.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Gordon Linoff thanks for your help, the code works well